# Deserialize an object (dll-class)

Tags: c#, serialization, plugins, dll

I have a problem with my dll-files. I'm writing a program which can be extended with some plugins. I use an interface for these plugins and I can read and use them in my program. Each plugin contains a serializable class, which contains some simple fields. 
I can serialize these classes with a binary-formatter and save them to disk. But when I try to deserialize my saved file, I get an exception: "The assembly ... can not be found".

Where do I have to register my dll-plugins so that my programm can find the assembly?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I highly recommend using [MEF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648.aspx) for plugin, it is part of .NET 4.0.

On the other hand, DLLs are loaded from bin folder. If you put them anywhere else they cannot be found. Now if you still insist having a "plugin" subfolder inside your bin, then you may manually load the assemblies at the startup by using `Assembly.LoadFile`.

Comment: Hi. When my dll-file is saved to the bin-folder, the assembly can be found. But we have to use a special folder for plugins.
I tried "Assembly.LoadFrom()", too, but it did not help. I get an Assembly-object, which tells me a lot of different things like other interfaces, but the binaryformatter still doesn't know the assembly :(

Comment: `Assembly.LoadFrom` will work but the problem is the DLLs can have dependencies and you might have to put the dependencies in the plugin folder as well.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the plugin dll and all it's dependencies are in the same directory (or the GAC).

Answer (score 0):

Look here
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/netfxbcl/thread/e5f0c371-b900-41d8-9a5b-1052739f2521

In my case executing assembly and plugin assembly are in the same folder but I exception "The assembly ... can not be found" is throw.

I wrote following class

```
internal class FromLoadedAssemblyBinder : SerializationBinder
    {
        public override Type BindToType(string assemblyName, string typeName)
        {            
            Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(assemblyName);
            return assembly.GetType(typeName);
        }
    }
```

and using

```
_binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
_binaryFormatter.Binder = new FromLoadedAssemblyBinder();
```

The code is simple but it works fine in my project.